# Unix piping - echo and cat

Tags: bash, unix, echo, cat, piping

I am having trouble with the following command in Unix Bash Shell:

```
echo "This is some text" | cat dashes - dashes
```

"dashes" is a file containing the line of text: 
"---------------------------------"

From my understanding, the left command's stout stream becomes the right commands stdin stream. What I expected to be printed was:

```
This is some text
---------------------------------
```

But what actually printed was this:

```
---------------------------------
This is some text
---------------------------------
```

---

So I have two questions:

1. What is happening when the echo pipes into the cat, to make the given output?
2. How does the " - dashes" at end of the command work?

Comment: As `man cat` will tell you, `-` means STDIN, so `cat dashes - dashes` means con*cat*enate `dashes`, STDIN and `dashes`.

Comment: @Biffen How does the "This is some text" get in between the two lines of dashes? I would expect the STDIN to be concatenated to the front, rather than the back

Comment: The different ‘files’ (STDIN being one of them) get concatenated in the order that you specify them.

Comment: Ahhhh it just hit me, thank you so much I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected because `-` in between 2 file names means print all the data from **stdin**. Take this example:

```
date | cat dashes - dashes
---------------------------------
Fri May 29 05:49:05 EDT 2015
---------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not a bash-ism incidentally, but an implementation detail of cat (and many many other unix tools).

Comment: Ah I see, the - gets replaced by whatever is in STDIN! Cheers

Comment: Rather think of `-` as a name for the file `STDIN`.